# Redirect to 404 if query string contains anything

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, query-string

Despite searching extensively I cannot seem to find an answer, so I apologise if this has been asked before and I've simply missed it.

I have a site with only static URIs, all SEO friendly, hard-coded in the .htaccess file. Unfortunately we're seeing a lot of other sites linking to us with query strings searching for unsavoury things. This is hurting our search ranking and we'd like to return a 404 for anything with a query string.

I've tried variations on the following, without success:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^404.php/? [R,L]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule (.*) /404.php? [R,L]
```

This should achieve what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above which is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule (.*) /404.php? [R,L]
```

doesn't return 404 to search engines.It just displays the 404 page. Use the line below to accomplish the goal

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule (.*) /404.php? [L,R=404]
```

keep in mind even though this will eliminate the spam links from google index, it will also limit wp-admin and search functionalities.